# XmlnsPrefix not enforceable

Tags: wpf, xaml

Creating a XmlnsPrefix is a pretty neat idea and is easy to do

```
[assembly:XmlnsPrefix("http://temp.com/controls", "controls:")]
```

However as far as I know it's not enforceable. Is it possible to restrict changing the prefix in xaml? I would like every developer on my team to use the standardized syntax. We already use tools like Xaml Styler and Style Cop Analyzers to make code more standardized however I would love for this to be possible and preferably without expensive heavy extensions like ReSharper.

Comment: What do you mean by enforce? Produce compile-time error when you try to do that?

Comment: I would assume if I add a prefix that it would compile a warning at the very minimum

Comment: Well I think you realize already that you will have to implement such behavior yourself. Cannot imagine it is implemented already somewhere, because this requirement is quite unusual. If you have used resharper it would be easy to implement that, but otherwise have not much ideas.